# I got "Could not resolve dependencies" error when I run maven install command

Tags: maven, pom.xml, nexus

I added private nexus repository urls in pom.xml to install some dependencies from inhouse nexus repository.

But eclipse still shows "Missing artifact error" messages in pom.xml file

here is command line error messages when I run mvn install command

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project diffapi: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.my:diffapi:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.aaa.bbb.poi.jar:poi:jar:5.14.4, com.aaa.bbb.poi.jar:poi-skp-search-client-util:jar:5.14.4, com.aaa.bbb.poi.jar:poi-util:jar:5.14.4, com.aaa.bbb.frame:ndds-log:jar:1.4.6, com.aaa.bbb.frame:ndds-util:jar:1.4.6, com.aaa.bbb.frame:ndds-monitor-agent:jar:1.5.0, com.aaa.bbb.frame:ndds-web-utility:jar:1.5.0, com.aaa.bbb.frame:ndds-context:jar:1.5.0: Failure to find com.aaa.bbb.poi.jar:poi:jar:5.14.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

it seems maven only access maven central instead of private nexus repositores

And this is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.my</groupId>
<artifactId>diffapi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>diffapi</name>
<description>diff api server for rmi and rest result</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <ndds.frame.version>1.5.0</ndds.frame.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aaa.bbb.poi.jar</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aaa.bbb.poi.jar</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-skp-search-client-util</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aaa.bbb.poi.jar</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-util</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aaa.bbb.frame</groupId>
        <artifactId>ndds-log</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aaa.bbb.frame</groupId>
        <artifactId>ndds-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aaa.bbb.frame</groupId>
        <artifactId>ndds-monitor-agent</artifactId>
        <version>${ndds.frame.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aaa.bbb.frame</groupId>
        <artifactId>ndds-web-utility</artifactId>
        <version>${ndds.frame.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aaa.bbb.frame</groupId>
        <artifactId>ndds-context</artifactId>
        <version>${ndds.frame.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>AAA-releases</id>
        <name>AAA-releases</name>
        <url>http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/AAA-releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>AAA-snapshots</id>
        <name>AAA-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/AAA-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing repositories where your project will be deployed after building with repositories which are used as sources for the dependencies in your project.  You haven't actually specified a custom 3rd party repo, so Maven is giving up after failing to find the artifacts in the central repo.  From the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management):

> Whereas the repositories element specifies in the POM the location and manner in which Maven may download remote artifacts for use by the current project, distributionManagement specifies where (and how) this project will get to a remote repository when it is deployed. The repository elements will be used for snapshot distribution if the snapshotRepository is not defined.

So, try adding a `<repositories>` element which contains the extra repos which you want available for the custom JARs in your build:

```
<project>
    ...
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>AAA-releases</id>
            <name>AAA-releases</name>
            <url>http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/AAA-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>AAA-snapshots</id>
            <name>AAA-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://IP:PORT/nexus/content/repositories/AAA-snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <repositories>
        <!-- fill in with the actual details of your repo here -->
        <repository>
            <id>REPO ID</id>
            <name>REPO NAME</name>
            <url>YOUR URL GOES HERE</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks It works now!! Actually I didn't know the different of distributionManagement tag and repositories tag. however my code is successfully run in intellij so I didn't realize what problem is in my pom.xml. The error only occured in mvn command.

Comment: Neither did I, until I read the documentation.  Actually, I _did_ know about the `<repositories>` tag, but not distribution management.  My answer should at least point you in the right direction.